# Where clause bool fail

Tags: c#, linq

```
class Foo{
        public string FooText { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Bar> Bars{ get; set; }
}

class Bar{
        public Foo Foo { get; set; }
        public Language Language { get; set; }
        public string FooText { get; set; } 
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
}
```

I have a collection of Foo. I want to get Foo and Bar with Language with language Name "English"

```
fooCollection.Where(x => 
                    x.Translations.Where(q =>
                                         q.Language.LanguageName == "English"));
```

and this fails. `Can not convert Foo to bool.`

How can i get this done. Essentially i want to get Foo and Bar whose Language is english.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.Where` returns a collection, it's not a bool change it to [.Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx)

```
fooCollection.Where(x => 
                    x.Translations.Any(q => 
                                       q.Language.LanguageName == "English"));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 x.Translations.Where
```

returns a collection, not a boolean.

```
fooCollection.Where(x =>
                    x.Translations.Where(q =>
                                         q.Language.LanguageName == "English")
                    .Count() > 0);
```

should do the trick.

Edit:
Added parenthesis due to user2864740 comment.
(But I agree that .Any() is the preferred way.)

Comment: instead of `.Count>0` use `.Any()`

Comment: (While I also recommend Any, it would need to be `.Count() > 0` as Where returns IEnumerable/IQueryable here.)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Sure, `.Any()` does, but `.Count > 0` does not.